# Migrate Sharepoint Online to a new Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, content-migration

A client A has an existing Sharepoint Online and a client B hasn't.
They want to merge into a new domain Office 365.

So, it is possible to migrate an existing Sharepoint Online to a new one included in a new Office 365 domain ?

I only find information about Sharepoint on premise to O365.
What about Sharepoint Online ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no OOTB/simple way to move the site collection in the Office 365. I am thinking two possible way.

**Option 1**

You are able to manually save the sites as the templates and import to the new tenant as a workaround, it will not break the files and the structure in a site except the permissions.( One thing, if your site collections is publishing then you have to [turn off the publishing feature](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/203562.aspx) before performing the steps.)
For details, please check this.

[Moving SharePoint sites](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/12028.aspx)

**Option 2**

Think about the 3rd party tools, all supported from Office 365 to Office 365 move (i.e sharegate, metalogix etc. They have trial version as well.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'm going to check this out.